# Java Nio Server Design

Tags: java, server, nio

I'm developing a Client-Server Java app and i thought Nio would be the best for the server.

I have a thread with a ServerSocketChannel listening for connections so i make a Dispatcher thread that registers connections in the selector and checks if you can read or write on the keys.

So i have a couple of questions of how to design the server:

1. Do i place all connection in just 1 Dispatcher? If otherwise how many connections should a Dispatcher hold?
2. Depending on 1) should I read and write in Dispatcher threads or make new threads for that?
3. What would be the best way of protecting the connection? Is AES a good idea?
4. What would be the best way of designing the connection holder so server can be reused without much effort?

Comment: Do you have a good reason not to build it on top of HTTP?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Do I place all connection in just 1 Dispatcher?

Sure.

> If otherwise how many connections should a Dispatcher hold?

As long as a piece of string. Start with one and see if you really have a problem.

> 2. Depending on 1) should I read and write in Dispatcher threads or make new threads for that?

Do it all in the same thread.

> 3. What would be the best way of protecting the connection? Is AES a good idea?

The best way is via SSL, using the `SSLEngine`, but it's not for the faint-hearted. There are numerous questions here about it.

> 4. What would be the best way of designing the connection holder so server can be reused without much effort?

I don't understand the question.

It sounds a bit as though you're running before you can walk. I would start with a blocking-mode server using `java.net`, and eventually `SSLSockets,` and see if you really have any kind of a performance problem with that that needs solving. It isn't very likely unless you're going to have tens or hundreds of thousands of connections.

Comment: are you suggesting we use one thread for Dispatching, I/O and processing? I think that is not efficient way of using hardware.